# Missing .dll file prevents MiKTeX package manager from opening

Tags: packages, miktex

I recently installed MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7 (64-bit; single-user installation), but shortly after I installed it, the Package Manager stopped opening.  When I try to open it, I get the following error message:

`The program can't start because MSVCP120.dll is missing from your computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.`

(When I try to open "Settings", I get the same message.  The updater opens correctly.)

When I look at the MiKTeX binaries folder, I find `msvcp100.dll` and `msvcr100.dll`, but not `msvcp120.dll`.  Where can I find the correct version of this file?

Comment: Did you try google : `msvcp120.dll`

Comment: @touhami Yes.  Among other things, I found an answer to a StackOverflow question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726910/exe-gives-error-msvcp120-dll-is-missing-for-win7x64) that advised against simply downloading the file.  It may be that that advice does not apply to this case, though.

Comment: @touhami Downloading the file turned out to work perfectly.  Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to another site, the missing dll is part of the MS Visual C++ 2013 redistributable. Free from Microsoft:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784
Try it and let us know.

Comment: I had the same problem: Could not start MikTeX package manager again after update, with error message saying that MSVCP100.dll (sic!) is missing. 
Searching for MSVCP100.dll leads to this site: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-performance/msvcp100dll-missing/9a687c31-0619-4ee9-b511-020985e29b5f?auth=1 
where I followed the link "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)". Installing this package from the Microsoft website immediately solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It was updated (or created) on June 10. It is in the `miktex-vc120` package. Perhaps you should synchronise repositort, via the Package manager, then install it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the information about the package.  In my particular case, though, needing to use the Package Manager to get the file is a significant drawback of this solution!  Fortunately, after download the file per RobtA's suggestion, everything works.

Comment: As the package contains other `dll`s, it might have been safer to download `miktex-vc120-bin-x64.tar.lzma` from CTAN ([direct link to the page](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages) ), then simply unzip it  `at the root` of the distribution and refresh the FNDB.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem and I found a solution in this blog http://blog.fix4dll.com/how-to-fix-cant-start-camstudio-because-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer/ . U need just lo load new msvcr100 to the needed folder and reboot computer. It should fix a problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Answers that only contain links are not very useful because the page linked to might disappear in the future. It would be more useful to copy he salient features across.

Comment: well in the near future I hope it will not disappear